# Search for the occurrence of a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to find an optimized way to identify if a specific set of values exists in a list.

For example, lets assume the following list of records in a table

```
Id          Value
1           A
2           B
3           A
4           C
5           A
6           B
7           C
8           C
9           A
```

I'm trying to find a way to check how much times the sequence {A, B} or {A, B, C} occurs, for example.

I know I can do this with cursors but I was checking if there's any other option that would be preferable in terms of performance.

The result I'd expect would by something like this:

```
{A, B}: 2 times:
{A, B, C}: 1 time.
```

I'm using Sql Server.

Comment: Do you mean with no gaps?

Comment: I'm using SQl Server in this case.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use the ANSI standard functions `lag()` and/or `lead()`:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lead(value) over (order by id) as next_value,
             lead(value, 2) over (order by id) as next_value2,
      from t
     ) t
where value = 'A' and next_value = 'B' and next_value2 = 'C';
```

Comment: I don't think that is an *optimized way*.

Comment: Until you get another answer, this is the most "optimized" way

Comment: That works just fine. Thank you very much. It is a lot more optimized than iterating it through cursors, that's for sure. :)